# What is wrong with my code that inserts two variables into one table field?

Tags: php, mysql

This is my code:

```
$datum=$_POST['datum'];
$mesto=$_POST['mesto'];
```

$details should be something like this

```
$detalis = "Datum rodjenja:" . $datum . "; Mesto rodjenja".$mesto;
```

Then I need to do this:

```
$query="insert into table('1','2','3') values('$details','something1','something2')";
```

but it won't work. It's insert everything else,but won't insert $detalis.

Comment: it wont insert my $details in table. It's insert everything else, but don't insert $details.

Comment: @AleksandarVasic: That is not an error description. You haven't performed enough debugging. What SQL error do you get from that query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use backticks `` instead of single quotes for column name. you are not allowed to enclose column names in quotes.

Escape the `$details` variable using [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).

```
$details = mysql_real_escape_string($details);
$query="insert into table(`1`,`2`,`3`) 
           values('$details','something1','something2')";
```

Answer (score 1):

`$detalis` is not `$details`, and column names are delimited with backticks not single quotes. And you forgot to prevent SQL injection. And you should implement some *basic* error detection so that you know why your code "doesn't work".

```
$details = "Datum rodjenja:" . $datum . "; Mesto rodjenja" . $mesto;
//   ^^^

$details = mysql_real_escape_string($details);

$query = "INSERT INTO `table` (`1`,`2`,`3`) VALUES('$details','something1','something2')";
//                             ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^               ^^^

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
// ^ run query WITH ERROR CHECKING
```

Comment: `mysql_escape_string` is really deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

remove the **'** from column name (Remove the single quote from column name).

you cannot add **;** into the details string because it is end statement of mysql.

Comment: It's within a string. That's fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try `mysql_real_escape_string($details)` instead of `$details` in inserting command.

Answer (score 0):

Why won't it work?

You mispelled: `$detalis` and `$details` I presume should be the same thing.

There is no need to quote your table columns. You also need to escape the semi-colon in the query, for example:

```
$query="INSERT INTO table (1,2,3) VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($details)."','something1','something2')";
```

Comment: No, you don't need to escape a semi-colon within a string. `mysql_real_escape_string` won't even do it.

Comment: On the contrary: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?37,132124,132124#msg-132124 However yes you do need to escape the semi-colon manually.

Comment: Works fine for me in MySQL v5.1.42 (which isn't exactly bleeding-edge), and that random forum post is a single forum post from 2007. I can't find any mention of this problem in the manual, nor in the bugs list, open _or_ closed. I'm going to go ahead and say that that forum poster made some other mistake, or that it was a bug in the ODBC driver.